# Combining SQL Google Search with own SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am pretty new to SQL queries.

I have a [google SQL Search example](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3?csw=1)

```
SELECT cID,
       (6371 * acos
               (
                  cos(radians(51.455643)) 
                * cos(radians(latCord)) 
                * cos(radians(longCord) - radians(7.011555)) 
                + sin(radians(51.455643)) 
                * sin(radians(latCord))
               )
        ) AS distance
FROM breitengrade
HAVING distance < 50
ORDER BY distance 
LIMIT 0, 20
```

and a own SQL query

```
SELECT breitengrade.cID
    ,breitengrade.latCord
    ,breitengrade.longCord
    ,Pages.cIsActive
FROM breitengrade
INNER JOIN Pages ON breitengrade.cID = Pages.cID
WHERE cIsActive = '1'
```

How can I combine these 2 queries into one so that I can get one single result set?

Comment: Add some sample query result (for both queries), and show us the combined result.

Comment: google query: distance: 6.1270510776493765 ID: 176
distance: 34.567985906684235 ID: 174
distance: 35.79004122185893 ID: 182
distance: 36.27236174844419 ID: 177

Comment: own query: ID: 174 lat 51.3358678 long 7.4713417
ID: 176 lat 51.4025161 long 6.9881057
ID: 177 lat 51.34298 long 7.50224

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT breitengrade.cID,
       breitengrade.latCord,
       breitengrade.longCord,
       Pages.cIsActive
       (6371 * acos
               (
                  cos(radians(51.455643)) 
                * cos(radians(latCord)) 
                * cos(radians(longCord) - radians(7.011555)) 
                + sin(radians(51.455643)) 
                * sin(radians(latCord))
               )
        ) AS distance
FROM breitengrade
INNER JOIN Pages ON breitengrade.cID = Pages.cID
WHERE cIsActive = '1'
HAVING distance < 50
ORDER BY distance 
LIMIT 0, 20
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply,  this is my error message: An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT breitengrade.cID, breitengrade.latCord, breitengrade.longCord, Pages.cIsActive (6371 * acos ( cos(radians(51.455643)) * cos(radians(latCord)) * cos(radians(longCord) - radians(7.011555)) + sin(radians(51.455643)) * sin(radians(latCord)) ) ) AS distance FROM breitengrade INNER JOIN Pages ON breitengrade.cID = Pages.cID WHERE cIsActive = '1' HAVING distance < 50 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0, 20 ': SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1305 FUNCTION Pages.cIsActive does not exist